# Conjugacy classes in reductive group under adjoint action of parabolic subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, permutations

Given a reductive group $G$ over a finite field and a parabolic subgroup $P$ , I wonder what are the orbits in $G$ under the adjoint action of $P$. This should be standard, but I can only find results on the orbits inside $P$.

Actually, I would like to know which (say) permutation representations of the parabolic $P\to \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$ admit an extension to a $P$-equivariant map of sets $G\to \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$. But I do not know in which context this question falls.

I would already be very happy for an answer in the case  $G=\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and the $(2,1)$- parabolic $P=(\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)\times \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p))\ltimes \mathbb{F}_p^2$. I want to play around with a group-theoretic version of connection and parallel transport on the Grassmanian $\operatorname{Gr}(3,2)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Thanks and greetings,
Simon

Comment: This reminds me of §4 in *Wolf, Joseph A.*, Representations that remain irreducible on parabolic subgroups, Differential geometrical methods in mathematical physics, Proc. Conf. Aix-en-Provence and Salamanca 1979, Lect. Notes Math. 836, 129-144 (1980). [ZBL0449.22016](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0449.22016)...